What is the Calvinist/Reformed solution to the Problem of Hell?
How could a loving and just God condemn people to eternal conscious torment, a punishment that seems disproportionate to any finite sins committed in a limited human lifetime? If God desires all to be saved, why would He create souls knowing they would end up suffering forever, and why make salvation dependent on beliefs that many people never have a fair chance to accept? How can eternal damnation be reconciled with perfect divine justice when humans have such limited knowledge, varied cultural contexts, and finite lifespans to make the right choices? What kind of loving parent would allow their children to suffer eternally when they have the power to save them, and how could any finite sins warrant infinite punishment?

Eternal punishment is God's solution to the disparity between sinful nature and Divine Righteousness.  None need perish, for all that is required is . . . .  faith.

First of all we don’t understand the magnitude of our sins against God because we don’t understand the magnitude of God’s holiness. Our sins aren’t small—they’re infinitely sinful. See the parable of the unmerciful servant for biblical support for this idea, along with Romans 1. Also see Romans 9 or 10, I forget which one for Paul’s Spirit-inspired argument answer to this question about his right to make people as he chooses and still judge them. This isn’t a matter of one theology or another, but of Scripture.

The problem is that a consistent Calvinist is unable to give a good answer, the doctrines and writings of John Calvin are clear. God's choice, pleasure, and incomprehensible will determined who gets to be in heaven or hell.

This may be somewhat nit-picky but there is a very important item in your title that does not appear in the rest of your question. A believer in Universal Reconciliation may answer that many of these things are logically impossible and the answer is that hell is temporary and remedial / purifying.

The question prejudices any answer by stating multiple interpretations that make it in effect a layered straw man. For example, salvation is not dependent on beliefs that anyone doesn't have a fair chance to accept. It's the reverse. Look around at some of the bizzarely obvious unscientific culpable behaviour around today. People don't just have one fair chance - they have an almost infinite number of unfair chances to repent. And again the talk about conscious eternity is prejudicial since hell is outside of time and difficult to represent from a conscious point of view.

Even within the purely human realm, we see people who ask forgiveness not because they are sorry that they committed a crime/sin, but purely because they are sorry that they got caught/punished, and will go back to their old ways once the slate is wiped clean (at least, if they even ever truly stopped!)  If an omniscient God knows the truth of your heart, then that includes the truth of your sincerity: this entire question is based on a presupposition that the souls in Hell have stopped sinning after their 'finite lifespan' ends: i.e. that it's "infinite punishment for finite sin"

Great comment @Chronocidal. As I was trying to expound in the small space available in the comments there seem to be layers of deception just lurking in the question itself, but it's still doing a useful job bringing out those aspects of people's usual assumptions when they are just starting out on considering ... I don't know if this is the wrong terminology, someone may correct me: the philosophy of religion.

This article from a Reformed perspective addresses some of the questions: Universalism and The Reality of Eternal Punishment: The Justice and Mercy of God.
A good starting point is Romans. It is true that people have varying amounts of knowledge of God’s ways, but Romans says that all people are given, through nature, sufficient knowledge.
As to the extreme degree of punishment, your logic is backwards. Instead of looking at our crimes and saying by our logic eternal punishment is too harsh, we must flip it around. God is all knowing and superior at logic, as well as being just. If he sets the punishment as eternal torment, then our sins must be worse than we can imagine. Remember, the cost of our sin includes the crucifixion of His infinitely beloved Son. Just try weighing that in the scales of justice.

Excellent response. Very well balanced. Up-voted +1.

God have foreknowledge of the fate of one soul, how come God continue to allow pro-creation and gives soul, knowing fully, that these souls will be eternally damn, and God is helpless to save them?

This looks (from what I can read here; I haven’t had time to read the article yet) like a good answer but content from the linked article really needs to be pulled into and quoted from the answer so it can stand on its own. Among other things external links can and do go dead eventually. Or if the answer as it stands has already done that, it would help to add some wording making that clear.

Hell is only a problem to those who try to justify before God their actions (which includes sinful actions). Hell is a problem to those who consider their sin to be 'finite', despite the fact that their infinite Creator disagrees with that view. Hell is a problem to those who think they can 'balance' the scales of justice in their favour by doing more 'good' deeds than 'bad' deeds. Hell is only a problem to sinners who try to make light of their sin, disagreeing with God's righteous verdict.
Hell is not a problem to 'Calvinists' / Reformed Protestants because they have come to agree with the just punishment God will render to all who obstinately refuse to repent before him, for their many sins. They have humbly repented, agreeing that even their deeds which are viewed from the human perspective as 'righteous' are actually as filthy rags in God's holy sight (Isaiah 64:6). They recognise that they deserve hell for their myriad offenses against their Creator, but that God has gracious provided the way of total pardon, undeservedly so, and have put faith in that wonderful gift of grace.
They are no longer stubborn children, refusing to take parental counsel to save themselves grief, blaming their parents for what is actually their own foolishness. They have learned that salvation has nothing to do with "limited knowledge, varied cultural contexts, and finite lifespans to make the right choices". It has to do with believing God who says, "Look unto me, and be ye saved, all ye ends of the earth" (Isaiah 45:22). But some refuse to even look to God.
Hell is not a problem for 'Calvinists' / Reformed Protestants, because those who want God to judge them on the basis of their own merit, and supposed righteousness, will be so judged, and found guilty. That's because nobody can merit God's free pardon. But pride causes many to insist that they have to do something to complete what they think is a transaction, an offer, which God cannot complete: he is waiting helplessly for people to accept an offer. Oh, really?
Calvinists / Reformed Protestants know from the Bible that salvation from sin, death and hell was wrought and completed by what Jesus did. Salvation is all of God, so that nobody can say they contributed towards it, or deserved it to some degree. Pride is a great sin, which is why the Bible is clear that our works will not save us, for if they could, we would boast in our works, but all the glory has to go to God (Ephesians 2:9). Hell is not a problem for us, for we know God has saved us from the curse of sin, which results in hell - and we simply point others to Christ, what he has done, that they might trust in his finished work on the cross, and be freely pardoned because Christ bore our punishment, in our stead. Salvation is not dependent on having to believe a set of doctrines; it is about putting faith in Christ.
The bottom line is this: "Christ Jesus came to save sinners" (1 Timothy 1:5). But if you don't think you are a sinner, or that your sins are transient, fleeting, and not all that bad, really... then Christ will not save you. Only those who are cut to their hearts at their sins, will come to Christ. The Holy Spirit brings people to that conviction of sin.
EDIT: Due to many comments re. my answer, which I did not see until the suggestion was made that they all be moved to Chat, I just want to thank everyone for their comments. I will not respond as I'm not here to get into 'Chat', nor to defend myself, plus some comments are going off-topic now. Many of those points have already been asked about, and answered on this site. I appreciate all interest shown, however.

Can I ask specifically about this part of the question? "...when humans have such limited knowledge, varied cultural contexts, and finite lifespans".
This is problematic to me, because consider the following example. Person A is born in Africa, and never heard of Christianity, let alone the concept of sin, their entire life. He lived in a morally upstanding fashion, spending much of his spare time feeding the needy. Yet one time, as a child, he stole an apple from a stall, thereby dooming him to hell.
(cont. next comment)

Person B was a serial adulterer, and drank, smoked, and committed frequent domestic violence against his spouses. Yet a week before death, they found Christianity, and repented for their sins, granting them God's grace and allowing passage to heaven.
Does this example not seem entirely unjust?
Also, as a secondary response, this line of thinking has been rebuked by Pope Francis, who has gone on record saying that even atheists can go to heaven, given a sufficient balance of good deeds.

@ApexPolenta I'm not Anne, but FWIW I think that bob's answer below addresses your questions somewhat (of course, I don't know if it had already been posted by the time you commented). Also, if the Pope actually said that and meant it that way, then he is without a doubt not saved. (Obligatory disclaimer that I am not Roman Catholic myself, but the Bible is incredibly clear on this point and so I think it transcends denominations. I imagine a Catholic might respond that his remarks were misinterpreted or taken out of context, which might be true for all I know.)

@JoshGrosso let me try to get this straight: You (and bob) are saying that certain people are created by God, with full knowledge that they will never even get the opportunity to repent for their sins, and are doomed to hell?
I can perhaps begrudgingly grant that any sin is deserving of eternal punishment in your worldview, and that the only path to salvation is repentance before God. But to not even offer some of his creations any chance to repent? For that matter, why is death the deadline for repentance if existence continues afterward?

@ApexPolenta This is where Purgatory plays an important role, to those precious soul, who thru no fault on their own, but have goodwill, are definitely saved, in mysterious ways unknown to Church. (lumen Gentium p. 16).Pope Francis is SUPREMELY correct about the Atheist going to Heaven, eventually after passing thru purgatory. Bible Alone Believers are spreading the errors in embracing Faith Alone, as they are boxing the infinite mercy of God to a set of books called bible.

@ApexPolenta I'd disagree with "never even get the opportunity to repent." A few things come to mind: 1) The opportunity is always available to everyone, whether they choose to accept it or not. 2) If someone does not know about Jesus per se, but recognizes their own sin and truly desires God's mercy, Jesus can always make a way to reveal Himself (e.g. in a dream, by compelling a missionary to visit their location in particular, etc.). 3) In general, although I can't confidently answer such questions, I still have faith that a perfectly good, merciful, and just answer does exist.

^This. Remember that Peter was sent to Cornelius a gentile to bring salvation to his household by preaching the gospel to him and his family. Up to that point he knew only the Law which was insufficient to save him, but the Holy Spirit had planted in his heart a desire to know God, and was clearly drawing him to himself, and worked divinely though a missionary—the apostle Peter—to bring that about exactly as Josh Grosso said. And we know that there will be in heaven people from every tribe nation people and tongue! We sell God way to short if we think he cannot draw someone & then save them.

No matter where they are in the world. But it is always through the gospel—there is no other name under Heaven by which people must be saved.

And Purgatory is not in the Bible. There is no working off of sins after death, which is bad news for those relying on it and good news for those relying on the grace given by Jesus—we who believe in Him will never have to suffer the just penalty of our sins because Jesus paid it for us in full. This is why he said on the cross “It is finished”, and why Paul said in Romans 8, “There is now no longer any condemnation for those who are in Christ Jesus”.

@bob Ok, so are you saying that Person A from my example has never existed, because God would have commanded a missionary to save them? I find this statistically unlikely, given there are only so many missionaries, and something on the order of 10 billion people alive today.
But even putting that aside, doesn't everyone deserve a chance at repentance? Most unenlightened people are better than Person B - are they just left to their own devices as unfortunate happenstance of their birthplace?

Also, this question is now even more important than I expected: Why is death the deadline for repentance? If one's existence continues past death, wouldn't it be much fairer (and easier for God) to allow for a Purgatory to exist?

Answering in reverse order. The problem with Purgatory is that our sin is infinite, and that’s why an eternity is insufficient to pay your own sin debt and why punishment for sins is eternal. That and Jesus fully paid all the sins of those who believe in him. So it wouldn’t help those who die unbelieving, and would be unwarranted for those who die believing.

Regarding the first question, a better answer is that God knows those who are his, and as Jesus says in John 6:37, “Everyone the Father gives Me will come to Me, and the one who comes to Me I will never drive away”. How that works in each and every case I don’t know, other than ultimately it is through Jesus—they come to Him. It is never any other way. One way that can happen is through missionaries being sent by God to that person. Also note that Jesus is the narrow Way and “few find it” (see Matthew 7:14). Note that this fewness…

…is irrespective of nation; God shows no partiality. But it shows that without God drawing us to himself, our sinful nature makes us utterly sinful, and any good works we may do are insufficient to pay our debt, or as it says in Romans 3, there is no one good, not even one. We as humans have a deeply warped view of our standing before God without the grace of Jesus. We think we’re good. We’re not—we’re evil, all of us, as Jesus himself said when he talked about how we give good gifts to our children as human parents. That’s why God’s grace is such good news! We’re deservedly on death row!

@bob I think I may need to seek a pastor to ask these questions. No offense intended - it's perfectly fair to say you don't know, but that answer leaves me unsatisfied. Thanks for your time anyway.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

This does not even answer the question, you have not given the Calvinist response to the problem of hell. Human beings condemned to the lake of fire do not suffer forever for Jesus said fear him who can destroy the body and the soul in hell, so those souls will ultimately be destroyed. Saint John also says everyone who believes in him perishes not, I do not think that means eternal suffering, there is ultimate destruction awaiting them in hell.

I will solely address the issue of Calvinism, as it seems none of the other answers (as of writing this) do. Likely because it is indefensible.
I however must say that I believe strict calvinism is heresy. I will do my best to answer as to their perspective on this subject. This includes considering hell as a kind of "place" and at the end... well you will see.

Historical context
So, the reformation happened because the Catholics were doing some shady dealings and many disagreed with those practices. They rightly pointed out that only God forgives sins, and that selling forgiveness was wrong. Out of this environment John Calvin arose.

Related Calvinist doctrine
John Calvin was a prolific writer who composed the first set of New Testament Bible commentaries. Calvin looked at Biblical terms like predestination, election, chosen, called and foreknew and interpreted these verses to mean that somewhere in eternity past God elected, or predestined, some people to go to Heaven and some to go to Hell. Individuals had no say-so in the matter of their eternal destiny.
I will not go into great detail about the fundamental pillars of this, but if you want to review it the acronym is TULIP.
The important ones for this question are L and P.

Limited atonement
Perseverance of the Saints

Basically God has only deigned to save some people and because God's will is impossible to be stopped anyone who is destined to be saved remains saved and will never fall.

What does that mean?
The only reason some are in heaven and some are in hell, is because it pleased God for them to be there.
A consistent Calvinist believes that God actively predestined some to hell (as Calvin does) or he did so by choosing not to offer what would have surely delivered them from hell to heaven, which is unconditional election and selective regeneration. This reality is the product of God's wish, pleasure, and counsel.

that God by his eternal and immutable counsel determined once for all those whom it was his pleasure one day to admit to salvation, and those whom, on the other hand, it was his pleasure to doom to destruction. We maintain that this counsel, as regards the elect, is founded on his free mercy, without any respect to human worth, while those whom he dooms to destruction are excluded from access to life by a just and blameless, but at the same time incomprehensible judgment. (John Calvin, Institutes of the Christian Religion, vol. 2, bk. 3, chap. 21, sec. 7)

Calvin classifies God’s good pleasure to doom this innumerable group of people, whom he created, to such a ghastly and unalterable fate, which he did not have to choose, as "incomprehensible judgment."

Article 15: What peculiarly tends to illustrate and recommend to us the eternal and unmerited grace of election, is the express testimony of sacred Scripture, that not all, but some only are elected, while others are passed by in the eternal election of God; whom God, out of his sovereign, most just, irreprehensible and unchangeable good pleasure, hath decreed to leave in the common misery into which they have willfully plunged themselves, and not to bestow upon them saving faith and the grace of conversion; but leaving them in his just judgment to follow their own ways, at last for the declaration of his justice, to condemn and punish them forever, not only on account of their unbelief, but also for all their other sins. And this is the decree of reprobation which by no means makes God the author of sin (the very thought of which is blasphemy), but declares him to be an awful, irreprehensible, and righteous judge and avenger thereof. (Canons of Dordt. FIRST HEAD OF DOCTRINE
Of Divine Predestination)


Thought experiment: Afterlife and Eternity
The thought experiment worth considering now is... fast forward to the afterlife. The elect holy gazing from heaven into hell at the endless masses enduring unimaginable, unquenchable, unparalleled agony and torment. One of the elect exclaims "God is Holy" and all of the elect immediately roar amen and hallelujah. Regardless of redeemed or damned, God's perfect and unlimited righteousness and holiness are irrefutably evident.
One of them then proclaims "God is love"... but who would look from heaven at those who had 0% of a chance to avoid their fate and believe it? Who would see the evidence in front of them and believe in the clearly arbitrary, whimsical, uneven love of God? (That is assuming they have free will to contemplate such a blasphemy)
While God clearly dealt with the elect and the damned in holiness, and the elect in love, it is impossible to truthfully say God dealt with the damned, the reprobate, in perfect love, salvific love. Seeking to explain how God is perfect love and yet withholds his salvific love from those he created and predetermined for eternal torment... is something Calvinism cannot do.

Short and direct answers.
How could a loving and just God condemn people to eternal conscious torment, a punishment that seems disproportionate to any finite sins committed in a limited human lifetime?

Those in hell deserve it! We do not understand how bad sin is.

If God desires all to be saved, why would He create souls knowing they would end up suffering forever, and why make salvation dependent on beliefs that many people never have a fair chance to accept?

This is a mystery, we do not comprehend God's judgement.

How can eternal damnation be reconciled with perfect divine justice when humans have such limited knowledge, varied cultural contexts, and finite lifespans to make the right choices?

God did not elect them to be saved, they did not receive the selective salvation of God. Just as in the old testament only some were the chosen people of God.

What kind of loving parent would allow their children to suffer eternally when they have the power to save them, and how could any finite sins warrant infinite punishment?

This is something we cannot comprehend, God's judgement is holy, perfect and incomprehensible.



I will here omit many of the fictions which foolish men have devised to overthrow predestination. There is no need of refuting objections which the moment they are produced abundantly betray their hollowness. I will dwell only on those points which either form the subject of dispute among the learned, or may occasion any difficulty to the simple, or may be employed by impiety as specious pretexts for assailing the justice of God. -John Calvin, Institutes of the Christian Religion, Section 21 closing statement)


While some parts of this answer are great it completely fails to address the problem of misrepresenting that people are damned without getting a fair chance. I think one might argue that this could be an axiom about God's love and conclude that people who genuinely had no fair chance would receive mercy (if there are any of those).

@NeilG According to the Institutes of the Christian Faith by John Calvin this is not a misrepresentation. I agree that people are not damned without getting a chance, and I personally am shocked that calvinism is still around today due to how blasphemous it is towards the nature of God's Love.

First of all we don’t understand the magnitude of our sins against God because we don’t understand the magnitude of God’s holiness. Our sins aren’t small—they’re infinitely sinful. See the parable of the unmerciful servant for biblical support for this idea, along with Romans 3:

21Then Peter came to Jesus and asked, “Lord, how many times shall I
forgive my brother who sins against me? Up to seven times?” 22Jesus
answered, “I tell you, not just seven times, but seventy-seven times!e
23Because of this, the kingdom of heaven is like a king who wanted to
settle accounts with his servants. 24As he began the settlements, a
debtor was brought to him owing ten thousand talents.f 25Since the man
was unable to pay, the master ordered that he be sold to pay his debt,
along with his wife and children and everything he owned. 26Then the
servant fell on his knees before him. ‘Have patience with me,’ he
begged, ‘and I will pay back everything.’ 27His master had compassion
on him, forgave his debt, and released him.

(Matthew 18:21-27)
Note that the ten thousand talents was a sum of money estimated to be worth at least millions if not billions or more in USD today—an infinite sum!

9What then? Are we any better? Not at all. For we have already made the charge that Jews and Greeks alike are all under sin.10As it
is written:
“There is no one righteous,
not even one.
11There is no one who understands,
no one who seeks God.
12All have turned away,
they have together become worthless;
there is no one who does good,
not even one.”c
13“Their throats are open graves;
their tongues practice deceit.”d
“The venom of vipers is on their lips.”e
14“Their mouths are full
of cursing and bitterness.”f
15“Their feet are swift to shed blood;
16ruin and misery lie in their wake,
17and the way of peace they have not known.”g
18“There is no fear of God
before their eyes.”h
19Now we know that whatever the law says, it says to those who are under the law, so that every mouth may be silenced and the whole world
held accountable to God.20Therefore no one will be justified in His
sight by works of the law. For the law merely brings awareness of sin.
Righteousness through Faith in Christ >     (Philippians 3:1–11)
21But now, apart from the law, the righteousness of God has been revealed, as attested by the Law and the Prophets.22And this
righteousness from God comes through faith in Jesus Christ to all who
believe. There is no distinction, 23for all have sinned and fall short
of the glory of God,24and are justified freely by His grace through
the redemption that is in Christ Jesus.
25God presented Him as the atoning sacrificei through faith in His blood, in order to demonstrate His righteousness, because in His
forbearance He had passed over the sins committed beforehand. 26He did
this to demonstrate His righteousness at the present time, so as to be
just and to justify the one who has faith in Jesus.

(Romans 3:9-26)
Also see Romans 9 for Paul’s Spirit-inspired  answer to this question about God’s right to make people as he chooses and still judge them:

19One of you will say to me, “Then why does God still find fault? For
who can resist His will?” 20But who are you, O man, to talk back to
God? Shall what is formed say to Him who formed it, “Why did You make
me like this?”h 21Does not the potter have the right to make from the
same lump of clay one vessel for special occasions and another for
common use? 22What if God, intending to show His wrath and make His
power known, bore with great patience the vessels of His wrath,
prepared for destruction? 23What if He did this to make the riches of
His glory known to the vessels of His mercy, whom He prepared in
advance for glory— 24including us, whom He has called not only from
the Jews, but also from the Gentiles?

(Romans 9:19-24)
This isn’t a matter of one theology or another, but of Scripture. We err greatly when we make God out to be only loving or only holy, just, and judging. God is all of these to a degree far beyond limit or our understanding. I understand that the idea of eternal punishment, of some being eternally lost makes us uncomfortable. And it should! But this should drive us to witness to and pray for the lost and to serve the church in its mission to the lost, not deny the truth! But to deny the truth of Scripture that there is eternal punishment and there are those who unfortunately will justly receive it is to make God a liar because this doctrine is throughout Scripture. God is love, but God is also holy and just and righteous. Consider God’s declared name to Moses or the words in Jeremiah of how were to boast:

5And the LORD descended in a cloud, stood with him there, and
proclaimed His name, the LORD. 6Then the LORD passed in front of Moses
and called out:  “The LORD, the LORD God,  is compassionate and
gracious,  slow to anger,  abounding in loving devotion and
faithfulness, 7maintaining loving devotion to a thousand generations,a
forgiving iniquity, transgression, and sin.  Yet He will by no means
leave the guilty unpunished;  He will visit the iniquity of the
fathers  on their children and grandchildren  to the third and fourth
generations.” 8Moses immediately bowed down to the ground and
worshiped.

(Exodus 34:5-8)

23This is what the LORD says:  “Let not the wise man boast in his
wisdom,  nor the strong man in his strength,  nor the wealthy man in
his riches. 24But let him who boasts boast in this,  that he
understands and knows Me,  that I am the LORD,d who exercises loving
devotion,e justice and righteousness on the earth— for I delight in
these things,”  declares the LORD.

(Jeremiah 9:23-24)
In response to a comment, Evangelicals absolutely have the answer for this question because it’s in the Bible as noted above. We may not like the message in our own human understanding. We may want it not to be there in our sinful weakness. But it’s there by God’s sovereign wisdom. Will we fully comprehend the answer in our minds in this life? No, no more than Peter and the other core disciples comprehended how Jesus’ command to “eat his flesh and drink his blood” could be true and good, yet unlike his other disciples they didn’t rely on their understanding and leave him, they trusted, proclaiming him to have the words of life and staying with and in him (see John 6:22-66)! They did what Proverbs 3:5-6 (“5Trust in the LORD with all your heart, and lean not on your own understanding; 6in all your ways acknowledge Him, and He will make your paths straight”) tells us to do, the opposite of what Eve did in the garden, deceived by Satan:

1Now the serpent was more crafty than any beast of the field that the
LORD God had made. And he said to the woman, “Did God really say, ‘You
must not eat from any tree in the garden?’ ” 2The woman answered the
serpent, “We may eat the fruit of the trees of the garden,3but about
the fruit of the tree in the middle of the garden, God has said, ‘You
must not eat of it or touch it, or you will die.’ ” 4“You will not
surely die,” the serpent told her. 5“For God knows that in the day you
eat of it, your eyes will be opened and you will be like God, knowing
good and evil.” 6When the woman saw that the tree was good for food
and pleasing to the eyes, and that it was desirable for obtaining
wisdom, she took the fruit and ate it. She also gave some to her
husband who was with her, and he ate it.

(Genesis 3:1-6)
Eve was deceived into trusting Satan’s false accusation against God when it sounded good and true to her in her own understanding rather than trust the God whom she knew and walked in the garden with, who made her. We can likewise be deceived.
At the end of the day will we trust God at his word, believe him, and worship him in faith, including faith in his character and goodness, or reject his word and along with it him? The choice is ours. And so is the consequence whatever we choose.

I can't help calling out the assumptions that creep in here. There's nothing in the text that shows that Eve had any misunderstanding at all. All the aspects of the fruit presented by the serpent were apparently true and accurate, and did not contradict any word from God. What the serpent actually introduced was the concept of disobeying God despite his warning, framing, in fact, God's advice as selfish, and suggesting that Eve could achieve power to rival God. Her sin was not due to misunderstanding the nature of the fruit, it was in her defiance of God as the source of all life.

@NeilG I think we mostly agree—Satan didn’t lie about the fruit granting wisdom though as you say he lied about the extent of that wisdom (implying that it would make her rival God). That said she was deceived, as 1 Timothy 2:14 says, “14and Adam was not deceived, but the woman was deceived and became a transgressor.” She was deceived by Satan’s lie that she would not die, a false accusation against God b/c it would make God’s statement that they would surely die for eating the fruit out to be a lie.

So the literal lie that deceived Eve, and by which Paul rightly said Eve was deceived in 1 Timothy 2:14 was “you will not surely die”, not “your eyes will be opened”, but the implied lie, as you mention, was God has lied to you to keep you from becoming wise like him—maybe even as wise as him. And she stepped out of reliance on God into self-reliance, as you rightly mention.

Thanks for the 1Tim2:14 @bob that's interesting. Brings in that she was deceived. Presumably at a minimum she must have believed she would not die, although there may be other aspects, such as believing she could rival God. She evidently believed God was lying though. That may be her key transgression I suppose: God was lying, God wasn't protecting her, God was even trying to stop her from being better than him. Pretty high arrogance ... I can't think of a good enough word right now to describe how bad that is.

Agreed. That transgression, which Adam sealed and brought into the world by following Eve in eating brought about the separation Christ died to end—we weren’t created to rely on ourselves, to live for ourselves—but with God, in God, for God. And through Jesus we can return to Him, relying on Him and living for Him (and having that close relationship with Him again) on earth, with its perfect fulfillment in heaven. It’s something God has been showing me more and more lately. I already knew the gospel of course, but didn’t realize the extent that it permeates the whole Bible.
